# Any cmd text editor which support common text editing shortcuts?

Tags: linux, text-editor, command-line

Is there a shell text editor that uses common keyboard shortcuts for navigation and editing?

I need the following features as much as possible:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + (<kbd>c</kbd>/<kbd>x</kbd>/<kbd>v</kbd>) for copy, cut & paste
- selecting by holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and using the cursor keys <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + (<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>) for word navigation
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>  to select all
- selecting with mouse (if possible through putty connection)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> to undo
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> to save
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> to create a new file
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> to close

Comment: I'm trying to dig into emacs. There is a very nice distribution called spacemacs, which adds evil mode for vim emulation, and many other features. This was the first thing that I run into. It turns out there is a mode called cua-mode, that covers most of your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not fixed to these special shortcuts, **mcedit** might work for you:

[image: mcedit]
<sup>*mcedit* with the "edit" menu opened (source: [tuicool.com](http://www.tuicool.com/articles/v2MRn2); click image for larger variant)</sup>

*mcedit* is part of the [Midnight Commander](https://www.midnight-commander.org/) file manager, but also can be used separately. I'm using it daily, and am pretty satisfied with it: it's fast, supports syntax highlighting, and you can extend it with your own specifications.

Let's see how it matches your requirements:

- **Copy/cut/paste:** uses different hotkeys, rather inspired by those used for file operations: you mark text with <kbd>F3</kbd> (alternatively, mark block-wise using <kbd>F13</kbd> or via the menu shown in the screenshot.<kbd>F5</kbd> copies marked text to where your cursor is (copy-paste), <kbd>F6</kbd> moves it (cut-paste).
- **Select text:** as described, hit <kbd>F3</kbd> once, then move the cursor keys as you described to mark the selection, press <kbd>F3</kbd> again.
  I've just checked: Also works exactly as you've described, by holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while moving with the cursor keys – so "full match" here.
- **Word navigation:** Exactly as described by you.
- **Mark all:** Works, but again a little different: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Home</kbd> to move to the start of the file, then <kbd>F3</kbd> to activate marking, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>End</kbd> to mark to the end of the document.
- **Selecting with mouse:** Works. Emulates the internal <kbd>F3</kbd> marking when no key pressed, and "X-marking" (for your "global clipboard") with the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key pressed.
- **Undo:** Yes, but it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>

A bunch of additional possibilities, like jumping to a given line number, search (and replace), and copying to / inserting from a "clip file" (to move text between files) makes this a "round thing". To play at your nick: PHP syntax highlighting included (I use it frequently to edit PHP files) :)

[Midnight Commander](https://www.midnight-commander.org/) is part of pretty any distribution's repository, and thus simply installed using `apt-get install mc` (Debian and derivates) or `yum install mc` (RPM-based distributions). Read more on *mcedit* by enlarging the screenshot, or follow up to [the article it was taken from](http://www.tuicool.com/articles/v2MRn2), or see [the Midnight Commander's home page](https://www.midnight-commander.org/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. While it is a set of really useful stuffs, I still prefer a lightweight text editor with Windows-like keyboard shortcut.